# Does MongoClient.connect emitt anything?

Tags: mongodb

Does the MongoClient.connect function emitt any events, e.g. db.on('error')? I could not find anything in the 'mongodb' driver documentation.

In my application, I should monitor the connection and write a warning messages to a log whenever the connection is lost, even if I have "autoReconnect:true" active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MongoClient.connect](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/MongoClient.html#.connect) returns promise or uses callback. So it does not emit anything. But the object `Db` which you receive when the method resolved inherits EventEmitter. So you can listen it for this [events](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Db.html#event:authenticated)

```js
MongoClient.connect(url, options, function(err, db){
  db.on('error', /* log error */ )
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was exactly that I was looking for,

What a great community here!